# CollapsingToolbar Up Arrow

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Most tutorials and materials on `CollapsingToolbarLayout` show how when `expanding` the layout, the Up arrow stays only where the minimum height for `Toolbar` is ([like this one](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#expanding-and-collapsing-toolbars)) but there are some implementations where the Up arrow moves along with the expansion and goes to where the expanded Toolbar is.

How I did it, it's like most implementations - the Up arrow hides unless the Toolbar is collapsed. Any idea how to change that?

**EDIT:**

**Activity**:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarDetails);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**activity.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/detailsCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/eventdetailico"
            android:transitionName="eventImage"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/addico"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkgrey">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEventPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do  you have code to show?

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: So you're looking for something like [from here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#expanding-and-collapsing-toolbars)?

Comment: No this is what I have right now. I'm looking for the Up arrow to move with the expanding Toolbar (it goes down it doesn't stay at the top)